# What is the gain of this capacitance measurement circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, capacitance, feedback, gain

To sense the capacitance value of a sensor, I found the following circuit.

[image]

My knowledge on analogue electronics isn't that great, so I'm not sure how I'd determine the gain of this circuit.

Vo is the output voltage I need, the peak value detector and Vdc can be ignored.

So what is the gain, Vo/Vs, in this circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick Rf to have a high resistance relative to the impedance of Cf at the input frequency, the gain before the peak detector will be approximately -Cs/Cf.

That's a consequence of the feedback impedance being XCf || Rf ~= XCf and the normal equation for the closed-loop gain of an inverting op-amp amplifier.

One would normally pick the resistor in such a way- typically the purpose of Rf is to provide a path for the bias current of the op-amp. At very low frequencies the gain will be less as the resistor influence manifests, and you can easily write an equation for the gain including the resistor and including the op-amp open-loop gain too, if you want.

Comment: So is the following correct: V_0/V_s = jwC_s/(jwC_f + 1/R_f)?

Comment: That's correct, but if you want the magnitude of the gain you'd do a bit more manipulation, which would make it a bit more clear when you can ignore Rf.